# Email address for uniquely identifying contest submissions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am building contest form and need to identify form submissions uniquely per user, is email address a good approach to uniquely identify users?

We are collecting simple information like first, last name, email address and no address information.

Comment: How many sites have you seen that use email address as the primary login?!?  Bah!!... oh.. wait.. there are lots and lots and lots.

Comment: Well, OP did say it was for a contest, so there's nothing stopping someone from bombarding submissions with different email addresses to improve their odds...

Comment: How can you differentiate between one person entering with two different email addresses and two people who happen to have the same name each entering with their sole email address?

Comment: @barrick bingo.. you cannot.. perhaps you can make them promise.. really really promise not to enter twice. :)

Comment: yes i am against using email address as the unique way of identifying the form, the post was meant to see what kind of responses i get as i am trying to convince my colleague not to do so!

Answer (score 0):

> is email address a good approach to uniquely identify users?

It's roughly as good as a username, which is to say not good.

The main difference between the two is that one (username) tends to remain unique while the other (email) does not: you switch providers or companies, change names when you get married, etc., but you rarely if ever change your username from a site to the next.

As an aside, a single email address is also occasionally used by the entire household or family.

For your particular case (a contest), other options include the IP address, setting a cookie, using browser characteristics, etc.

Bear in mind though that there is no magic bullet at the end of the day: someone who is willing to flood you with submissions will manage to do so, and the best you'll be able to do is detect it after the fact by mining the data you've collected.

Comment: can you suggest alternative to using email addresses?

Comment: @Syler: per my answer, username, unique cookie, IP address, browser characteristics...

Comment: And periods dont matter in gmail, which proves emails arent unique. addresses http://www.slate.com/blogs/future_tense/2013/08/01/dots_in_gmail_addresses_what_happens_if_you_leave_out_the_period.html

Comment: Hi Denis. What is your thought on a ticketing system. Basically I keep track of users by providing them a guid Id generated on server side. Please see my response below.

Comment: @Syler: Strictly speaking, this ought to be a separate question to comply with this expected format on this site. Or posted on another site or venue altogether, seeing how your question got down-voted and close-voted. (My email is on my profile, if you're interested in paid-for input.)

Answer (score 0):

Guys I have figured it out ! You use a ticketing system to trumph the email address problem.  When a user first lands on the page, they get a popup asking if they are a returning user or a new user. If they are a new user , I create a guid Id for them and minify it and ask them to store it in case they want to return and cast more ballots max of three. 
When the user returns I simply check the provided guid id in the db and see if its a match. 
What do you guys think ?